# How can I make sure one Upstart service starts before other non-Upstart (System V) service?

Tags: boot, upstart, init.d, init, sysv

Is there a way to run one `Upstart` service before another **non**-`Upstart` service (`system V`, to be more precise)?

Or I must "convert" my `Upstart` script to a `System V` script (if it provides such functionality at all)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This appears to be "mission impossible".

A workaround is - stop the auto start of the other (System V) service and then start/stop it from your own Upstart service (in pre-start and post-stop)